# Razor declarative helper used as javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Assuming i have a helper such as:

```
@helper AddErrorSpan(string error)
{
    <span class="error">@error</span>
}
```

I run in to issues attempting to call the helper in javascript.  For example:

```
if ($('#YearTextBox').val() == "") 
{
        $('#ErrorDiv').append('@AddErrorSpan("Year field is required.")');
}
```

This fails and causes a javascript syntax error because the helper returns a newline at the end.  This causes the trailing `');` to be pushed to the next line causing the syntax error.  Is there anything I can do to remedy this easily?  Currently the easy solution is to make the helper like this.

```
@helper AddErrorSpan(string error)
{<span class="error">@error</span>}
```

Since there's no break before the closing `}` the new line isn't returned from the helper and there is no javascript syntax error.  This is kind of annoying and just ugly to look at.  Is there a way to keep the helper from returning the newline when called in my javascript method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Javascript-encode the string by calling [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) when calling the helper.

This will escape the newline as `\r\n`, which will in turn be harmlessly swallowed by the HTML parser.

```
$('#ErrorDiv').append('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(AddErrorSpan("Year field is required.").ToString())');
```

Comment: Verbose :(. Why does it have to be so verbose.

Comment: @Raynos: If you want to, you can make a helper with a shorter name that calls this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [AjaxHelper.JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper.javascriptstringencode.aspx):

```
@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(value)
```

Or declare a helper to make it more succinct:

```
@helper JsEncode(string value) {
    @(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value))
}
```